# category of modules a Grothendieck category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be a finite dimensional $k$ algebra. Is the category $\mathrm{mod}(R)$ of finitely generated $R$-modules a Grothendieck category?

Comment: If and only if $R$ is trivial.

Comment: No, a Grothendieck category must have arbitrary coproducts. However, in the specific case many pleasant properties of Grothendieck category hold true, for example any object has an injective envelope.

Answer (score 1):

A Grothendieck category must have arbitrary coproducts. So the category of finitely generated modules over a nontrivial ring is never a Grothendieck category.

However, for a finite dimensional $k$-algebra $R$, some of the pleasant properties of a Grothendieck category hold in $\mathrm{mod}(R)$; the main example is that any object has an injective envelope: it's easy to prove that the injective envelope of a simple module is finite dimensional over $k$, so it belongs to $\mathrm{mod}(R)$.
Since every module in $\mathrm{mod}(R)$ has finite length, so it has finitely generated essential socle, the result follows.